# expressing volume of a set as iterated integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a set $Q = \{(x^3,y^3)|x^2+y^2\leq1\}$, and I would like to calculate the volume of the set. to calculate this volume through iterated integrals, I considered doing the following:

$Vol=\int_{-1}^{1}$ $\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx$

but this doesn't account for the fact that the coordinates are cubed. One question I have: would this integral yield the correct volume if I were to cube each of the boundaries? Help on how to proceed here would be appreciated.

Comment: Your set $Q$ doesn’t make sense. Can you please  proofread and edit?

Comment: Sorry, is it clear now? It is a set of coordinates. @TedShifrin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I provided my attempt, and a reason why I believe it is likely incorrect. Is that not what is asked of users here?

Comment: Your question seems good to me, I'm working on an answer and I'll get back soon.

Comment: So what is the equation of the boundary curve of your region? Maybe it would help to write points of your region as $(u,v)$.

Comment: I believe the boundary curve is the circle $x^2+y^2\leq1$

Comment: Nope. For each point $(x,y)$ on the circle you must look at $(x^3,y^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Our set $Q = \{\, (x^3,y^3) \mid x^2+y^2 \le1\,\}$ can be redefined as $Q = \{\, (x,y) \mid x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} = 1 \,\}$.

We can then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ in the above expression, granting

$$Q = \left\{\, (x,y) \mid x \in [-1,1], -\left(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \le y \le \left(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\right\}$$

Then, we have an integral expression for the area:

$$A = \iint_Q{\mathrm{d}A} = \int_{-1}^1{\int_{-\left(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}^{\left(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}x}$$

Comment: Fractional exponents are your friend.

Comment: Hahaha, I'll edit it to express the radicals as fractional exponents.